Problem with "divergent branches" after creating IntelliJ project and pushing to new Bitbucket repository
I am trying to push a new IntelliJ project into a new Git repository on Bitbucket, but it fails with a "divergent branches" message. I really want to use IntelliJ and not step out to the command line for basic version control actions, but it doesn't seem possible.
This is what I have done:

I created a new repository in the Bitbucket web application
I created a new project in IntelliJ: A Kotlin project with Gradle
In IntelliJ, I selected VCS / Enable version control integration
In IntelliJ, I went to Git / Manage remotes and added a new remote using the URL from the Bitbucket Clone button.
In IntelliJ: Git / Fetch
In IntelliJ: Git / Pull: Now I get the "You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them" message.
I ran this on the command line: git config pull.rebase false
At this point I get into a loop about "divergent branches" or that "main has no tracked branch".

I am using: IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.5 (Ultimate Edition)

Presumably you created a non-empty repo in Bitbucket, and also locally. Either clone a non-empty repo, or create an empty repo on the remote and push from the non-empty local repo.

@jonrsharpe Could you please turn that into an answer?

It seems that you have created one or more commits in bitbucket and in IntelliJ, i.e. locally. And since both start from an empty repository, they don't have a common ancestor and therefore can't be merged as on would normally do.
Depending on where you start you have various options how to get out of this:

Avoid creating any commits in Bitbucket or IntelliJ before setting up git and the remote.
This should avoid the whole problem completely. I haven't used Bitbucket in ages, but I guess it allows to create stuff like READMEs on repository creation. These are introduced by commits, which will cause the problems you described.

if you have commits on both sides and already tried the stuff you mentioned above follow this process to
a) fix the situation
b) understand what is going on.

open the Git view in IntelliJ (CMD-9 on MacOS)
You should see two branches. Probably called main and origin/main containing the local and remote commits respectively.

Use IntelliJ to check out origin/main and create a new branch. I assume you name it work for now. Make sure that branch is checked out.

In the Git view select the oldest local commit and cherry-pick it. Repeat for all local commits, starting with the oldest. Repeat for all local  commits.

Checkout main again. Perform a reset to work. Choose hard when asked how to perform the reset.



Now perform a git push on main.


All commands of course can be performed on the command line, and I actually recommend using the command line a lot for Git. Because it is faster, in my opinion often easier to understand, and I'm old.
Also you should be able to do the same thing with rebase but I have a hard time remembering the correct arguments for these cases.

I am not looking to solve the (latest of) the problems I encounter, but rather to be able to follow an instruction that keeps me out of trouble. Obviously this functionality should be provided in an "integrated" development environment but it is not.
